# Flutter make BG image as local stored image

Tags: image, dart, flutter

I have the following code to set my background image as an asset image:

```
Container(
   decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
         image: AssetImage("assets/bg.png"),
      )
   ),
```

I wanted to know if I previously stored an image to the device, how can I use it as a background image?

```
Future<File> _getLocalFile(String filename) async {
  String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
  File f = new File('$dir/$filename');
  return f;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can use `SharedPreferences` to track if you saved the previous image and then do what you need.

Comment: I know for sure that the image is saved, but how can I access it - I try using Image.file but is says I can't convert Image to ImageProvider

Comment: Use `FileImage` in that case.

Comment: Thank you, wasn’t aware of the FileImage class.

Answer (score 1):

`FileImage` will help:

```
CircleAvatar(
   backgroundImage: FileImage(File(this.filepath)),
),
```